# Writing error messages for unchecked errors?

Tags: java, error-handling

When I create checked error classes I usually include a message to display like so:

```
class ParseException extends Exception{
    public ParseException (String message) {
        super (message);
    }
}
```

Is it good programming practice to write an error message for an unchecked exception seeing as the program will be unable to continue anyway?
Sorry if it's not a great question, I'm new to java and couldn't find any discussion on the matter online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is good practice. The reason is that a developer who runs your code and encounters the error can see the reason for the crash, which is often better explained in an exception message than just by the stack trace. This of course means that the message has to be more meaningful than "An error occurred". But well written exception messages can go a long way in helping developers debug their own code while using someone else's (or even their own) code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a good practice, you can also use try-catch where you can even handle the exception or print the message and "throw" can also be used.
Like:
throw new ArithmeticException("demo");

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice. The message can explain what wrong is with the error. The message can help the develper to understand the error, and to resolve the problem.